# how can i get difference of two excel file in another file using python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, data-analysis

I have one file "product.xlsx" which has 13 columns and 2946 rows. And another file "product_filter.xlsx" includes 13 columns and 2609 rows.

product_filter has the same data, same column header, and same row data. just missing 333 rows.
I just want that 340 rows in a different file. for example, in product_remaning.xlsx.

I have very little idea about python. so, if possible write your as you explaining to the guy who does not have any idea about python.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas with the [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), [contact](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) should solve this for you. Something like this should work.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_name1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_name2)
print(pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False))
```